# Wordpress Comments Pagination

Tags: wordpress

I want to paginate comments section of my wordpress blog using ajax. How would i do that. I want to use ajax because if i use other paginate plug-in's the whole page will be refreshed which is not what i needed

Anyone with an idea ?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check out [paginate_comments_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_comments_links), then check out the [Enhanced Comments Display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Plugins_and_Themes_to_2.7/Enhanced_Comment_Display) functionality of WP 2.7 and up.  Your functionality might be pretty close to built in.  Why are you avoiding page reload?  Comment pagination is typically pursued because loading hundreds of comments on each page is time consuming.  Re-loading the post is not the processor heavy task.